# jQuery Password Validation 6-10 Charactors and 1 numeric value

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, passwords

I'm after a regular expression that can be called upon when my code checks password field, I currently have:

```
^.*(?=.{6,10})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

Even though the string specifies amount of characters, it seems to only validate when two numeric values are entered, having just one does not pass the keydown check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does work. You can try validation with

http://www.regexpal.com/

That being said it's probably your JavaScript. You might want to look into trying a keyup check instead.

However, you do have a bug. It will accept more than 10 characters.